# Table and Models in Swing

Tags: java, swing

The problem I have is that one of the screens of my system shows (graphically) a table with data from a person (ID, Name, Address, Phone,...). To handle this table, I made own model, a class that extends Abstract Table Model.

Now, when the user chooses a person and squeezes a (delete) button, I have to know who this person is, and remove it from the database. So I need a message like "getPersona" (or something similar) then I tell a database manager the person I want to delete.

The problem is that, thinking about the right design, I doubt who should give me the information I need: the table, using a message like "getSelectedRow"; or the model, using a message like "getPersonSelected".

Comment: can you add your current working code snippet to help people debug this issue?

Comment: From just reading your query, i can think of a method that is available in the TableModel which is something like yourTable.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex); which gives you a value at a given row and column index.

Comment: Can't you use JTable instead? it has a .getSelectedRow() method

Comment: getSelectedRow() return an int, index of the selected row, i think what is needed is that actual value; which can be fetched from the model

Answer (score 0):

you can take any column value (eg. ID)of the selected row and then use that value in the query
to delete that particular record.

UPDATE

Use following code

```
String id=(String)tablename.getValueAt(tablename.getSelectedRow(),0); 
delOrder(Integer.parseInt(id));
```

delOrder() method contains code to delete the row.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add this to your answer.